# 4 signed in root users?

Tags: kali-linux

I just started using encrypted usb persistence on my laptop.  I noticed when im restarting into my main OS windows 7, that kali asks me to confirm  that I want to restart because there's 4 root users currently on the machine. Is this normal?

Comment: How about checking when they logged in, what they were doing, etc?  Commands like `last` and `w` could be useful but also looking at the shell's history might prove helpful.

Comment: Thank you I ended up doing a clean hard drive install and im happy to report that issue is no longer appearing.